# Convert JavaScript XMLHttpRequest to Java

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I have a REST endpoint I need to query to get a token. The example is in JavaScript, but I need to use it from Java. Here is the JavaScript example from the API:

```
var requestXML=new XMLHttpRequest;
requestXML.open("POST",
    "http://longUri/SpecialServlet/token?user=example&password=example", false);
requestXML.send();

var loginToken = requestXML.responseText;
```

Here is my converted Java:

```
String theUrl = "http://longUri/SpecialServlet/token?user=realUsername&password=realPassword";
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(theUrl))
    .POST(BodyPublishers.noBody())
    .build();

HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
var foo = response.statusCode();
// foo always results in 401
```

I don't what I'm doing wrong. The rest of the data in `response` isn't helpful and `response.body` is an empty string.

I think the problem is in the type of Body for the POST, but I've tried several (e.g. `ofString()` and others), but it still always fails. Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Comment: DId you check how your url is parsed ? My 2 cents would go on your authentication not being sent

Comment: I don't see any authentication in the original JS.

Comment: Use the "Network" tab of your browser's dev tools to examine the actual request headers being sent. There are likely extra headers in the JS request, added by your browser, that are required by the server. Look up the meaning of each header you find, and decide whether you need to implement those yourself in the Java request.